# Sensenet: It is possible to change value on a row directly on a List view?

Tags: .net, sensenet

For instance, I have a requirement that consists to change the value of a row on a field based on a "Choice Field" component.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYHKC.png)

Comment: So the _Test field_ in your example is a _choice field_ (with several options), and you want to see a radiobutton group or a similar UI element (e.g. buttons or images) in the grid cell that lets you change the field value immediately, with one click? Do I understand your question correctly? (something is not right with the image, it is not visible here - although it is accessible when you click on it).

Comment: Yes, you understand my question .

Comment: Hopefully I can post an example later, but if you want, you can start experimenting with the feature called [cell templates](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Cell_Template#Content_List_cell_templates). This lets you define html fragments for columns in a grid. You store these cell templates (simple ascx files) under your list in the _CellTemplates_ subfolder. The name of the cell template must be _[FieldName].ascx_. The idea is that you make a simple ajax call from javascript to the Sense/Net REST api that changes the value.

Comment: You have access to the content in the current row using this pattern: `<%# (Container.DataItem as SNCR.Content).Path %>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just asked to confirm if exist a solution more quickly without scripting.